# Implement ACL in GAE + GWT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, spring-security

I want to create a Google App Enginge + GWT application that implements Access Control Lists (ACL) for resource management etc. Just a standard non-authenticated user/basic user/manager user/admin type thing. The user's account/user type would then determine their access to certain functionality in the web application.

The only decent example I have been able to find so far requires integrating Spring Security into the mix ([Spring Security in Google App Engine](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine)/), but as the tutorial mentions that it uses Spring MVC, I wonder if this is appropriate or should I look for an MVP approach?

Are there any good books/tutorials/open source projects that can provide a clear example of how to achieve ACL in a GAE +GWT application (specifically Java based solutions)?

Answer (score 3):

Spring Security is a very solid security framework; it does not require any coupling with Spring MVC, and it should be fully compatible with GAE/GWT. I have not used it with GWT per se, but I've integrated it into a bunch of different apps, some with non-Spring MVC frameworks, others which did not even use a web MVC. It has a little bit of a learning curve but is very well-documented and proven.

Comment: Thanks. At least I know I'm on the right track. I'm just failing to find a clear example tutorial/project to get up and running.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? The examples in the page you provided should be very easily adaptable to a vanilla GAE/GWT app, with the one exception that if you don't already use Spring, you will need to first get Spring into the mix, but that's fairly easy also (plus Spring IMO is a must-have in web app environments).